# Generating HMAC-SHA256 using AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, key, encryption-symmetric, amazon-kms

I want to generate HMAC-SHA256 value of a plain text using AWS KMS.

Is this possible to do this & without rotation? Since, I want to only use a single key for hashing all the plain-texts. I don't know much about AWS KMS, if possible could you share some resources that talk about HMAC generation using KMS.

Answer (score 0):

**AWS KMS encryption and decryption in ASP.NET MVC**
1 plain key : with the help of it you encrypt the data and delete it(key)(no need to save anywhere).

```
2.encrypted data key :- you need to save this key to decrypt the data( to decrypt the data first you got plain key from aws using encrypted data key) and with the help of plain key you decrypt the data.

Note you need aws kms credentials like :-
a)serviceEndPoint b)awsKeyForKMS c)kmsConfig

Name space need to add from nuget package

using Amazon.KeyManagementService;
using Amazon.KeyManagementService.Model; 

**1) Encryption :-**
AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig kmsConfig = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig();
            kmsConfig.UseHttp = true;
            kmsConfig.ServiceURL = serviceEndPoint;           
                //create client, specify Region end point or kms config
                AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(awsKeyForKMS, awsSecretKeyForKMS, kmsConfig);
                GenerateDataKeyRequest dataKeyReq = new GenerateDataKeyRequest();
                dataKeyReq.KeyId = keyARNForKMS;
                dataKeyReq.KeySpec = DataKeySpec.AES_256;//The length of the data encryption key. AES_256 to generate a 256-bit symmetric key.
                GenerateDataKeyResponse dataKeyResponse = kmsClient.GenerateDataKey(dataKeyReq);
                //read encrypted data key from memory
                MemoryStream streamCipherText = dataKeyResponse.CiphertextBlob;
               // need to save this key with encrypted data because with the help of it 
               // you can decrypt(you got plaindatakey) the data
                encryptedDataKey = Convert.ToBase64String(streamCipherText.ToArray());

                //read plain data key from memory
                MemoryStream streamPlainText = dataKeyResponse.Plaintext;
              // use this key to encrypt your data and than forgot this key
                plainDataKey = Convert.ToBase64String(streamPlainText.ToArray());    
               //your encryption logic
                Encryption encrypt = new Encryption();
                encrypt.EncryptTextForKms(PlainKey, "data to be encrypted")

**2.Decryption Data:-**

AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig kmsConfig = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig();
            kmsConfig.UseHttp = true;
            kmsConfig.ServiceURL = serviceEndPoint;
                //create client, specify Region end point or kms config
                AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(awsKeyForKMS, awsSecretKeyForKMS, kmsConfig);
                DecryptRequest decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest();
// use hare above created encrypteddatakey to get plaindatakey
                MemoryStream streamEncryptedDataKey = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedDataKey));//convert to stream object
                decryptRequest.CiphertextBlob = streamEncryptedDataKey;
                DecryptResponse decryptResp = kmsClient.Decrypt(decryptRequest);
                plainDataKey = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptResp.Plaintext.ToArray());
// your decryption logic
             DecryptTexts("encrypted data", PlainKey)
```